# Xamarin and Xcode update to iOS 10 and "Got a SIGABRT while executing native code..."

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

Following my upgrade of Xamarin and Xcode to the iOS 10 updates/releases my app began failing on launch. The app never even entered the *App.cs* constructor for me to begin debugging.

**Actual Error Message:** *"Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your application."*

Answer (score 1):

After spending many hours trying to solve this problem I finally got a clue from digging through the iOS Simulator logs.

**Detailed Error message:**

> Loaded assembly:
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BC0B1376-DDDF-4DD1-954D-1872603FA8E6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2AA663A3-986B-434E-83B9-E7D88A6616FE/VSProjectName.app/.monotouch-64/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
>   An unhandled exception occured.
>
> 2016-09-16 23:12:13.570 VSProjectName[5278:156681]  Unhandled
>   Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or
>   assembly or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not
>   be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the
>   Reflection-only loader context.
>
> File name: 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' 2016-09-16
>   23:12:13.570 VSProjectName[5278:156681] Unhandled managed exception:
>   Could not load assembly

**Answer**
In one of my shared class library projects, referenced by the Xamarin.iOS project, I had a reference to the .NET 4.5 version of the *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll* assembly, even though there was no code anywhere in either of these projects that was using this assembly.

The app kept crashing on launch because, this version of the *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll* assembly cannot run on a mobile platform.

**Removing *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations* from the list of references in the class library project solved the problem.**

Please note that, prior to me upgrading to Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) and Xamarin 4.2.0.680 for Visual studio, this code worked fine.